# Ayuda - Extraer numero de url para parsearlo a integer

Tags: android

he estado tratando de extraer de esta url el numero dentro de la seccion del archivo de imagen para poder cargarlos con glide en android studio

Ejemplo:
https://t-organizagroup.com/ws_easyhotel/public/api/imagen/local/local4.JPG
sin embargo no se como realizarlo

he hecho esto hasta ahora :

```
public int getNumber() {
    String [] urlPartes = urlImagen.split ("/");

    return Integer.parseInt (urlPartes[urlPartes.length -1]) ;
}
```

lo cual me devuelve este error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "local4.JPG"
```

Se que mi error esta al tratar de extraer el número pero no se como.
Gracias por su atencion.

Comment: Tienes un bucle en donde llamas los  url para extraer los números? Que pasaría si en lugar de "local" fuera otra palabra, también extraerías el numero ? Te sugiero ser especifico a la hora de realizar preguntas, revisa [ask], saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo he solucionado de la siguiente manera:

```
public int getNumber(){
    String urlImagen = "https://t-organizagroup.com/ws_easyhotel/public/api/imagen/local/local4.JPG";
    String [] urlPartes = urlImagen.split ("/");
    String numeroStr = urlPartes[urlPartes.length -1];
    int numero = Integer.parseInt(numeroStr.replaceAll("\\D+",""));
    return numero;
}
```

Lo que hago es: asigno a una variable de tipo String la última parte de la url, tal como lo haces tú (numeroStr), luego a través de la función replaceAll(), utilizo una expresión regular que toma todo lo sea caracter "\D+" y lo reemplaza con vacío ""; con esto tendrás solamente la parte numérica que finalmente lo parseo a entero, que es lo que buscas.

Comment: Gracias David, me devuelve el numero, sin embargo como el link es de un arraylist en un json, solo carga esa imagen, y cuando lo intento con el link del Pojo me sale este error:

Process: es.easyhotel.torganizagroup.easyhotelalpha, PID: 5157
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Comment: Nunca mencionaste lo del arrayList ni el Json, asegurate de especificar en tu pregunta todas las tecnologías que estás usando y si es posible el código de cómo generas el arrayList, el Json y cómo está armado tu POJO. Edita tu pregunta con todas esas especificaciones...

Comment: Si amigo, ya resolvi el problema cmodificando parte de tu solucion, gracias por la ayuda y perdon por no especificarlo antes